# mkd2pdf, wkhtmltopdf, how to make PDF for slide

Tags: css, markdown, wkhtmltopdf

I want to make PDF by [mkd2pdf](https://github.com/jdodds/mkd2pdf) which base on [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf)

It can generate PDF from markdown, it use a css file to control the style. just like this

```
h1 {
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

so, I can make a slide, and each `# h1 #` will be a new page. It has close to my goals that generate slide from markdown.

but the output PDF is A4 ratio, I need a 4:3 ratio which fit page to full screen. I think wkhtmltopdf have some option, or some print control css can control this, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the output PDF is A4 ratio, I need a
>   4:3 ratio which fit page to full
>   screen. I think wkhtmltopdf have some
>   option, or some print control css can
>   control this, but I don't know how.

See: http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html

> The default page size of the rendered
>   document is A4, but using the
>   --page-size option this can be changed to almost anything else, such as: A3,
>   Letter and Legal. For a full list of
>   supported pages sizes please see
>   http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qprinter.html#PageSize-enum.
>
> For a more fine grained control over
>   the page size the --page-height and
>   --page-width options may be used

And:

```
--page-height       <unitreal>      Page height (default unit millimeter)
--page-size         <size>          Set paper size to: A4, Letter, etc.
--page-width        <unitreal>      Page width (default unit millimeter)
```

---

**UPD:** Docs by this URL might be less outdated: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf --page-height=600 --page-width=800 readme.html readme.pdf` report error `unknow long argument --page-height=600`

Comment: It's `--page-height 600` - replace all the `=` with a space.

Comment: It's important to note that if you use `--page-height` you also need to define `--page-width` or else it will not work; you need to use both params in tandem.